# Exercise 6.5 on p.133 in "Introduction to Graph Theory 5th Edition" by Robin J. Wilson.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matching-theory

The definition of complete matching on p.129:

> More generally, a **complete matching** from $V_1$ to $V_2$ in a bipartite graph $G(V_1, V_2)$ is a one-one correspondence between the vertices in $V_1$ and some of the vertices in $V_2$, such that corresponding vertices are joined.

Exercise 6.5 on p.133:

> Prove that, if $G = G(V_1, V_2)$ is a bipartite graph in which the degree of each vertex in $V_1$ is not less than the degree of each vertex in $V_2$, then $G$ has a complete matching.

I cannot solve this problem.
My attempt is here:

Let $V_1 = \{v_{11}, v_{12}, \cdots v_{1m}\}$.
Let $\deg(v_{11}) \leq \deg(v_{12}) \leq \cdots \leq \deg(v_{1m})$.
Let $V_2 = \{v_{21}, v_{22}, \cdots v_{2n}\}$.

I think if $\deg(v_{1i}) = 0$ for some $i$, then $G$ has no complete matching.
So, we assume that $1 \leq \deg(v_{11})$.

We prove this exercise by induction on $m$.

If $m = 1$, then obviously $G$ has a complete matching.

$\cdots$

Comment: Do you know [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem)?

Comment: For those of us who don't have a copy of that book handy, could you tell us what theorems about matchings you have available?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes I know. This problem is for the section "Hall's 'marriage' theorem".

Comment: @bof Hall's 'marriage' theorem.

Comment: In that case, instead of a proof from scratch using induction, maybe you should try to show that the hypotheses of Hall's theorem are satisfied? Remind me, what are they?

Comment: You are right to point out that the exercise in the book is misstated, as there is a counterexample when all degrees are $0$. You should correct the statement to read: there is a **positive** integer $k$ such that every vertex in $V_1$ has degree $\ge k$ and every vertex in $V_2$ has degree $\le k$. Now let $A\subseteq V_1$, and let $B=\phi(A)$; you want to show that $|A|\le|B|$. (Of course you can assume that $A\ne\emptyset$.) You will have to use that hypotheses about degrees somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: Let $G = G(V_1, V_2)$ be a bipartite graph, and for each subset $A$ of $V_1$, let $\phi(A)$ be the set of vertices of $V_2$ that are adjacent to at least one vertex of $A$. Then a complete matching from $V_1$ to $V_2$ exists if and only if $|A| \leq |\phi(A)|$, for each subset $A$ of $V_1$.

Comment: Hint: Let $e$ be the number of edges between $A$ and $|B|$, where $B=\phi(A)$. What can you say about $e$? Can you use the given information to derive upper and lower bounds for $e$?

Comment: @bof $k |A| \leq e \leq k |\phi(A)|$ holds. So, $|A| \leq \frac{e}{k} \leq |\phi(A)|$. ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had in mind. Is it correct?

Comment: @bof Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your huge hints, bof.

We use the Hall's 'marriage' theorem:

> Let $G=G(V1,V2)$ be a bipartite graph, and for each subset $A$ of $V_1$, let $\phi(A)$ be the set of vertices of $V_2$ that are adjacent to at least one vertex of $A$. Then a complete matching from $V_1$ to $V_2$ exists if and only if $|A| \leq |\phi(A)|$, for each subset $A$ of $V_1$.

Let $V_1 = \{v_{11}, v_{12}, \cdots v_{1m}\}$.
Let $1 \leq \deg(v_{11}) \leq \deg(v_{12}) \leq \cdots \leq \deg(v_{1m})$.
Let $V_2 = \{v_{21}, v_{22}, \cdots v_{2n}\}$.
Let $A = \{w_{11}, \cdots, w_{1k}\}$ be any non-empty subset of $V_1$.
Let $\phi(A) = \{w_{21}, \cdots, w_{2l}\}$.

Since any edge which is incident on a vertex in $A$ is also incident on a vertex in $\phi(A)$, so $$\deg(w_{11})+\cdots+\deg(w_{1k})\leq\deg(w_{21})+\cdots+\deg(w_{2l}).$$

And,

$$k \deg(v_{11}) \leq \deg(w_{11})+\cdots+\deg(w_{1k}).$$

And,

$$\deg(w_{21})+\cdots+\deg(w_{2l}) \leq l\deg(v_{11}).$$

So, $$k \deg(v_{11}) \leq \deg(w_{11})+\cdots+\deg(w_{1k})\leq\deg(w_{21})+\cdots+\deg(w_{2l})\leq l\deg(v_{11}).$$

So, $$k \leq l.$$

So, $$|A| \leq |\phi(A)|.$$